# Restricting access to Site Public pages for select Users

Tags: configuration, liferay, liferay-6, administration

Is it possible to restrict access of Site public pages for a few Users through configuration?

Now by default in liferay anybody can access the Public pages [that is the reason they are named Public Pages :-) ] of any Site whether `Open`, `Restricted` or `Private`.

In our system we force login to access even Public pages, but once logged-in the User can see the public-page of any Site if he has the URL for it.

*To make the requirement more clear:*

I have 3 users in the system, `User01`, `User02`, `User03`.
I have 3 Sites - `Site01` (open), `Site02` (restricted), `Site03` (private)
These Sites have only one User respectively.

All these 3 users can see public-pages of all three Sites. So now what I want is that only `User02` should be an exception, that is `User02` should not be able to access the Public-pages of `Site01` and `Site03`.

Is this possible through configuration? Or will it require changes in liferay code (possibly through hook)?

Even if we can limit access to Public-pages for all Users who are not member of that Site that will also work?

Any ideas or help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your last question

> Even if we can limit access to Public-pages for all Users who are not
>   member of that Site that will also work?

This can be achieved by removing VIEW permission for Guest role for each of Public pages of site.

HTH,

Thanks,

Comment: Gr8! This might work with a little tweak for others also ... will check and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here are few steps to achieve this:

> 1. You can remove view permission from guest role(or all role as per your requirement) to specified page(here from public pages as per your
>      requirement) from manage permission tab of page.
> 2. Create a new role(which will allow view permission) and from manage permission of page assign this role view permission.
> 3. Now assign these newly created role to users to whom you want to have view access to pages

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to do as per the answer by @PankajKathiriya.